# Word order after "nein"

Tags: word-order, colloquial, spoken-language

While conversing with 2 native German speakers I said,

> Nein, sie gehen nicht.

And they corrected me to,

> Nein, gehen sie nicht.

However, Duden has this example sentence:

> nein, das ist unmöglich

Why did they correct my sentence?

Comment: Please provide more context. What did you want to say to them? What would it be in English?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mostly a phenomenon of spoken and colloquial language. The emphasis is somewhat different.

***Nein, sie gehen nicht*** is the unemphasized, outright negation of *sie gehen*. It could be used in a context like:

> A: Gehen sie heute Abend zum Konzert?
>
> B: Nein, sie gehen nicht.

They don't go (at all), but *nicht* isn't emphasized by the word order. The answer could as well be *yes, they go*. There's no contradiction here.

***Nein, gehen sie nicht*** has two principal use cases:

1. If a question is answered that way, it can be used to negate not the verb (e.g., *gehen*) itself, but the circumstances:

> A: Gehen sie *oft* zum Konzert?
>
> B: Nein, gehen sie nicht. (Sie gehen selten.)

2. It can furthermore act like the opposite of *doch*: an rather emphasized, contrasting answer. It could also be used to negate a *statement* (instead of a question:)

> A: Sie gehen heute Abend zum Konzert.
>
> B: Nein, gehen sie nicht!

This is like the complementary case of:

> A: Sie gehen *nicht* zum Konzert.
>
> B: *Doch*, gehen sie!

which features the same word order after *doch*.